# How to mark only one post as Featured post?

Tags: posts, meta-query, get-posts, featured-post

Am working on a blog page and I want to have a featured post as a banner.

I have no idea how can I make only one post can be marked as the "Featured" so if another post is marked as "Featured" it removes the old post from showing as featured.

I've tried using ACF (Advance Custom Field) checkbox to mark featured posts but my approach is incorrect. Here is my code.

```
  <?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'numberposts'      => 1,
    ) );

    if ( $myposts ) {
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
            setup_postdata( $post ); 
            if(get_field('featured_post')):
    ?>
```

Once I marked the other posts featured nothing shows up.

Planning to follow this [approach](https://smallenvelop.com/how-to-create-featured-posts-in-wordpress/) but I have no idea on how to remove the old featured posts.

Comment: You should check 'featured_post' with meta_key and meta_value, just like approach you're following, rather than looping through all posts. ACF fields are just post_meta values.

Comment: Your best bet might be to add a save/update hook for posts that clears the flag on other posts as you set a new one. Alternatively you could add a single blog-wide option value that is the ID of the featured post: you'll configure this elsewhere but it would then be trivially single-valued.

Comment: Could you please provide a code for this?